# Remove highlighted area in pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I highlighted the word in pdf using the code in the answer to the following question: [Highlight words in a pdf using itextsharp, not displaying highlighted word in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952183/highlight-words-in-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-not-displaying-highlighted-word-in-br)

Now I want to know how to remove those highlighted rectangles using iTextSharp.

```
private void RemovehighlightPDFAnnotation(string outputFile, string highLightFile, int pageno, string highLightedText)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(outputFile);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(highLightFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
        {                
            PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(pageno);                
            PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);                
            if (annots != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; ++i)                   
                {
                    PdfDictionary annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annots[i]);
                    PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);                                               
                    if (subType.Equals(PdfName.HIGHLIGHT))
                    {
                        PdfString str  = annots.GetAsString(i);
                        if(str==highLightedText)
                        {
                                annots.Remove(i); 
                        }                          

                    }
                }                  

            }
        }
    }
```

It removes all annotation but i want to remove particular annotation. 
Suppose i highlighted **united states** and **Patent Application Publication** in page no 1, now i want to remove united states alone. I will pass the text **united states**.

I refered this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652411/how-to-extract-highlighed-text-from-pdf-using-itextsharp). In that,  to get the highlighted text, you need to get the coordinates stored in the Highlight annotation (stored in the QuadPoints array) and you need to use these coordinates to parse the text that is present in the page content at those coordinates.

Comment: You mean the code adding highlights as part of the content, not the code adding highlights as annotations, I presume...?

Comment: I edited my question. Kindly check.

Comment: If I were you I'd add private data to the annotations I create which contain the highlighted phrase. When you want to remove the annotations for a given phrase, you can simply check that private data.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to get the highlighted annotation coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting the highlighted annotation coordinates

As the OP clarified, he actually wants to

> get the highlighted annotation coordinates

to extract the text from that area, check whether it matches the phrase in question, and (if it does) remove the annotation.

As the code in question always only marks a single rectangle with each annotation and chose the rectangle to only contain the text in question, he can simply use the annotation rectangle

```
annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT)
```

In a more generic case (i.e. for highlight annotations starting on the end of one line and ending at the start of the next), he'd need to check the quad points

```
annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS)
```

which describe a set of quadrilaterals.

E.g. in case of the sample from the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952183/highlight-words-in-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-not-displaying-highlighted-word-in-br) (highlighting the occurrence of *the word "support" on the third document page* of the OP's sample PDF), the method

```
private void ReportHighlightPDFAnnotation(string highLightFile, int pageno)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(highLightFile);
    PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(pageno);
    PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (annots != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; ++i)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annots[i]);
            PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
            if (subType.Equals(PdfName.HIGHLIGHT))
            {
                Console.Write("HighLight at {0} with {1}\n", annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT), annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

reports

```
HighLight at [224.65, 654.03, 251.08, 662.03] with [221.65, 654.03, 251.08, 654.03, 221.65, 663.03, 251.08, 663.03]
HighLight at [80.9, 574.13, 107.28, 582.13] with [77.9, 574.13, 107.28, 574.13, 77.9, 583.13, 107.28, 583.13]
HighLight at [209.3, 544.33, 235.67, 552.33] with [206.3, 544.33, 235.67, 544.33, 206.3, 553.33, 235.67, 553.33]
```

In particular those values are **not `null`** as the OP claims in his comment

> null value only i get for PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS) and annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT)

### An alternative approach

If I were the OP, I'd add private data to the annotations I create which contain the highlighted phrase. When he wants to remove the annotations for a given phrase, he can simply check that private data.

Text extraction, even from a limited area, is a very costly operation as the page content stream and a possible multitude of form xobject streams have to be parsed.

### A warning on loop design

The OP wants to remove the annotations in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < annots.Size; ++i)                   
{
    PdfDictionary annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annots[i]);
    PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);                                               
    if (subType.Equals(PdfName.HIGHLIGHT))
    {
        PdfString str  = annots.GetAsString(i);
        annots.Remove(i);                           
    }
}
```

The problem: If he is at index `i` and removes this annotation, the former `i+1`<sup>st</sup> annotation becomes the `i`<sup>th</sup> one. As the next annotation to check, though, is the now `i+1`<sup>st</sup>, that former `i+1`<sup>st</sup> annotation will not be checked or removed.

Comment: null value only i get for   PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS) and annotationDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT) I want either highlighted word or co-ordinates from annotation

Comment: `pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS)` obviously won't help.

Comment: I want either highlighted word or co-ordinates from annotation, OK, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I replace this  PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS); into PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS);  Thank you so much for your help.