# iTextSharp PDF Reading drawing markups using c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am developing a C# application. I am able to extract the other contents except the content found in drawing markups(as shown in example)[image]. Please help to get the working sample to extract the drawing markups in pdf. I am using the iTextSharp.dll in the project

Comment: Markup annotations are, as the word says it, annotations. Annotations aren't part of the content stream. How are you extracting the content? Are you sure you also took into account the annotations? Show us some code, but please read [How to extract text and anchor information from a PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-extract-text-and-anchor-information-pdf) and [How to get the author of a "free text" annotation?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-author-free-text-annotation) first so that you fully understand my comment.

Comment: If you want to extract text from annotations and content in one go, you might try something like described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34039833/1729265) for form field annotations.

Comment: I am extracting the content using PdfTextExtractor but I am looking only for the contents which are in markups.I tried using :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342500/itextsharp-pdf-reading-highlighed-text-highlight-annotations-using-c-sharp?rq=1                             
But I am not sure about the PdfName to be used for markups.I used annots but that didnt help me.